# Firebase Realtime Database Update Data - Android Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an edit page for the user profile in Firebase. I've tried a few different ways. But I could not update. Just a added as a new user to the database.

I am getting new values in the Alert Dialog. Please help me.

My Update Method Code's :

```
public void editAlert() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ProfilePage.this);

        View design = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_profile, null);

        final EditText editTextUserName = design.findViewById(R.id.username_editTextProfileEdit);

        final EditText editTextRealName = design.findViewById(R.id.realName_editTextProfileEdit);

        final EditText editTextSurname = design.findViewById(R.id.username_editTextProfileEdit);

        final EditText editTextEmail = design.findViewById(R.id.email_editTextProfileEdit);

        final EditText editTextPassword = design.findViewById(R.id.password_editTextProfileEdit);


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialoga = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfilePage.this);
        alertDialoga.setTitle("Edit Profile");
        alertDialoga.setView(design);
        alertDialoga.setPositiveButton("Finish", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                String username = editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();
                String realName = editTextRealName.getText().toString().trim();
                String surname = editTextSurname.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String admin = "false";
                String url = "test_url";


                String key = myRef.push().getKey();

                Users user = new Users(key,username,realName,surname,email,password,url,admin);


                HashMap<String,Object> data = new HashMap<>();

                data.put("user_email", email);
                data.put("user_name", realName);
                data.put("user_password", password);
                data.put("user_surname", surname);
                data.put("username", username);

                myRef.child(user.getUser_id()).updateChildren(data);

                Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Uptaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        alertDialoga.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });

        alertDialoga.show();
    }
```

My Create User Code's :

```
  // Sign Up Method
    // Kullanıcı Kayıt etme metodu
    public void signUp(View view) {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        final String imageName = "ProfileImages/"+uuid+".jpg";
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(signupPage.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Creating user record.. ");
        dialog.setMessage("User registration is in progress..");
        dialog.show();
        StorageReference storageReference = mStorageRef.child(imageName);
        storageReference.putFile(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // Url

                StorageReference newReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(imageName);
                newReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                        dowloadURL = uri.toString();

                        if (dowloadURL != null) {
                            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailText.getText().toString(), passwordText.getText().toString())
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(signupPage.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) /* Kullanıcı girişi başarılı ise bu çalışacak */ {
                                                Toast.makeText(signupPage.this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                String userName = user_name.getText().toString();
                                                String userSurname = user_surname.getText().toString();
                                                String username = user_username.getText().toString();
                                                String user_email = emailText.getText().toString();
                                                String key = myRef.push().getKey();
                                                String password = user_password.getText().toString();
                                                String imageURL = dowloadURL;

                                                Users user = new Users(key, userName, username, userSurname, user_email, password,imageURL, admin);
                                                myRef.push().setValue(user);
                                                Intent homePage = new Intent(signupPage.this, ProfilePage.class);
                                                startActivity(homePage);
                                                finish();
                                                dialog.dismiss();

                                            } else /* Kullanıcı girişi başarısız ise bu çalışacak */ {
                                               /*Intent signBack = new Intent(signupPage.this, signupPage.class);
                                                startActivity(signBack);
                                                finish(); */
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                            }



                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(signupPage.this, new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(signupPage.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }


                    }
                });


            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(signupPage.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
```

The download url comes from a separate image selection method, by the way.
My user creation codes are like this.

Comment: What isn't working about this code? Did you try a simpler version of that code (e.g. just writing a single, hard-coded value)? Did that work?

Comment: The code is running but not updating, adding new records. I haven't tried the simpler part.But in a course I was looking at it was simple and working. But when I try adding a new user with a different id.

Comment: Check my answer. As to @FrankvanPuffelen: He is using the push() method as a key, so that creates a new user every time. That is the error.

Comment: @YılmazYağızDokumacı Check my answer now.

Comment: @TaraIordanov okey, i check now.

Comment: @YılmazYağızDokumacı Check my simplified answer, and also my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that instead of storing a constant and valid key in your firebase database, every time you change your profile you create a new node. How so? Well, you do this:

```
String key = myRef.push().getKey();
```

Which every time creates a new node(that is why the push is there) and you get the key of that node. That is also why you create a new user, instead of updating your account profile. The correct way to do it is the following.

When creating your user get the key with this:

```
String key = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

After you create your User Object with this key, do the following:

```
myRef.child(key).setValue(user);
```

When you want to update your user, you can access the key the same way you created it. After getting all the update information and the key, then do:

```
myRef.child(key).setValue(data); //For updating
```

or

```
myRef.child(key).updateChildren(data); //For updating
```

Comment: No didn't work. Of course I share the code by updating the question.

Comment: There are 1-2 points in your new answer that I don't understand.

1 - String key = myRef.push().getKey(); yerine String key = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(); kullanacağım değil mi?

2 - After using it, you can push the push myRef.child (key) .setValue (user); do with?

Comment: I tried and its worked thank you. But not listed my recyclerview.Could this have something to do with the method of creating a new uuid?

Comment: Could be if you have not attached the value listener to the reference of UID key. It should myRef.child(uid_key).addOnSingleValueEventListener.

Comment: I was pulling the key directly from the Users class. Now that I'm testing, it pulls the right key from the class, but it doesn't list it. My Users List Code : prntscr.com/omju1d (I used printscreen because imgur site is banned in my country.) I just used a query to list the logged-in user

Comment: I solved the problem. I'd like to ask you one more question, if I may.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Get reference to update location 
DatabaseRefrence dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getRefrence().child(your child name in string);

//set value
Map<String, Object> hasMap = new HashMap<>();
hasmap.put("name","Ethrak");

//update reference 
dR.updateChildren(hashmap);
```